# Booleans: Where is the "Apply" option in Blender 3.0? How do I activate the boolean modifier?

Tags: modifiers

While following this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/NfD9Nc1KmYM?t=683), I encountered a problem where after applying the boolean modifier, the modifier's effect isn't apparent.
[image: I applied the boolean modifier to this box, which is supposed to be a gameboy]

[image: A series of object used to carve the holes into the gameboy]

[image]

If you look at the third image, where I've hidden the objects used to carve holes into the gameboy, you'll notice the boolean difference effect doesn't happen.

I appreciate the help.

Comment: Have you tried applying array modifier and then the Boolean?

Comment: @Nand27 I tried applying the modifier twice and still no result.

Comment: @moonboots I just did https://pasteall.org/blend/47b86247ac3241d3966891d9ea6a20ea

Answer (score 3):

The Apply button is available here, you can also select the modifier and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>:

[image]

In your case, flip the normals of your array object (*Cube.002*), or choose the *Fast* instead of the *Exact* option for the *Boolean* of the big object (*Cube.001*), and it will work fine:

[image]