# Boolean Difference - how to remove the "cutter" without having the effects disappear

Tags: modifiers

My boolean difference disappears when I delete the placeholder object that I created just for the difference.  Here are my steps.

1. Create a simple cube (Cube1).
2. Create another (Cube2), make it a bit smaller and move it so that part of it intersects the original cube.
3. Select Cube1 > Modifier Properties > Add Modifier > Boolean
4. Make sure the modifier is set to "Difference" and under "Object" associate it with Cube2.

[image: cubes intersecting]

[image]

The works as I would expect - in that the original cube has a section cut out of it... but I have to hide Cube2 to see it.  If I delete Cube2 the effect of the modifier on Cube1 gets deleted with it.

I can understand why - but I've seen videos where people can delete the "cutter" objects (Cube2 in this case) and the effects remain.  How do I make that happen?

Comment: Just apply the modifier

Comment: I don't have an "Apply" option... I'm using Blender 3.

Comment: Check this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/255821/86978

Comment: Also if you want to keep the modifier in an unapplied state, you can set it's Viewport Display mode to "Bounds" like [this](https://imgur.com/a/dZ05Wft). 

It also makes sense to enable the "Bool Tool" addon, which comes with Blender by default and does all this for you automatically. Enable that and then you can just select the cutter, select the receiving object and then push "Ctrl" and then "Numpad +" for union, "Num -" for difference, and "Num /" for intersection.

Comment: To apply a modifier in Blender 3x, just select it in the modifier panel so that it's outlined in blue and press CTRL - A. You can also click the down-facing arrow to the right of the line of icons in the modifier panel and select 'Apply'.